# Appending multiple rows of data to a table using jquery with Jquery tablesorter plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to append data returned from the database using this code:
This is the PHP script which passes the data from the database to jquery script:

```
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

if(isset($_POST['pageLimit']) && !empty($_POST['pageLimit']))
{
    $pageLimit=$_POST['pageLimit'];
}

else
{
    $pageLimit='0';
}



$pageLimit=$pageLimit;
$per_page=10;

$stmt=$conn->//query;
$stmt->bindparam(':pageLimit',$pageLimit);
$stmt->bindparam(':per_page',$per_page);
$stmt->execute(array($pageLimit,$per_page));

$count=$stmt->rowCount();

// echo $count;

$HTML='';

if($count>0){

while($row=$stmt->fetch()){

$HTML.='<tr><td>';
$HTML.=$row["PROJECT_ID"];
$HTML.='</td><td>';
$HTML.=$row["Project_Title"];
$HTML.='</td><td>';
$HTML.=$row["PI_Name"];
$HTML.='</td><td>';
$HTML.=$row["Start_Date"];
$HTML.='</td><td>';
$HTML.=$row["End_Date"];
$HTML.='</td></tr>';
}

$loadCount=$pageLimit+$per_page;
if($count>=$per_page){
  $HTML.='<div class="load_more_link">';
       $HTML.='<input type="button" class="button" value="Load More"
       onclick=loadData("'.$loadCount.'")>';
}


}
else{
    $HTML='No data';
}
echo $HTML;
?>
```

Below is my Main page where the data needs to displayed

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="/javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>

<script>
 $(function() {

  $(".tablesorter")
    .tablesorter({
      theme : 'blue',
      // this is the default setting
      cssChildRow: "tablesorter-childRow",

      // initialize zebra and filter widgets
      widgets: ["zebra", "filter","stickyHeaders"],

      widgetOptions: {
        // include child row content while filtering, if true
        filter_childRows  : true,
        // class name applied to filter row and each input
        filter_cssFilter  : 'tablesorter-filter',
        // search from beginning
        filter_startsWith : false,
        // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive 
        filter_ignoreCase : true
      }

    });
      // hide child rows
  $('.tablesorter-childRow td').hide();

  // Toggle child row content (td), not hiding the row since we are using rowspan
  // Using delegate because the pager plugin rebuilds the table after each page change
  // "delegate" works in jQuery 1.4.2+; use "live" back to v1.3; for older jQuery - SOL
  $('.tablesorter').delegate('.toggle', 'click' ,function(){

    // use "nextUntil" to toggle multiple child rows
    // toggle table cells instead of the row
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:not(.tablesorter-childRow)').find('td').toggle();

    return false;
  });

  // Toggle widgetFilterChildRows option
  $('button.toggle-option').click(function(){
    var c = $('.tablesorter')[0].config.widgetOptions,
    o = !c.filter_childRows;
    c.filter_childRows = o;
    $('.state').html(o.toString());
    // update filter; include false parameter to force a new search
    $('input.tablesorter-filter').trigger('search', false);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>


<table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Record Id</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>PI Name</th>
<th>Project Start Date</th>
<th>Project End Date</th>

  </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadData(pageLimit){
     $(".flash").show();
       var dataString = 'pageLimit='+ pageLimit;
     $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "collaborations_paging_test.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){ 
            $(".flash").hide();
            $(".load_more_link").addClass('noneLink');
            var outResult = $(result);
            $("#tablesorter-demo >tbody:last").append($('<tr>').append($('<td>').append(result).append($('</td>').append($('</tr>')))));
      }
  });
}
  loadData('0');
</script>
</html>
```

I am successfully able to retrieve the data and display it but it only displays on one column. 
I want to press load more button and get 10 more rows of data but in my case it seems to display all 10 records in column and it is putting it in single cell. 
I cannot input the data in other columns. 
It seems that tags "" in the php script that queries the database do not make any difference. I also followed this page http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-empty-table.html#
but it does not work. 
Javascript is relatively new for me and I am still learning few things so please bear with me.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php already returning the html with `<tr><td>.....</td></tr>` tags, which you are then appending into `<tr><td></td></tr>` tags.

instead of the .appends in your ajax success try this

$("#tablesorter-demo >tbody >tr:last").after(result);

if the "No Data" message from php is supposed to appear within the table, then you would want to return

```
$HTML = '<tr><td colspan=100>No Data</td></tr>'
```

Here is a simplified fiddle to see it http://jsfiddle.net/SeNYS/

Comment: It seems that the problem was Javascript I had in the php page.I found using that console.log showed javascript that was not necessary for in the php page.you are right that I do not need to attach `<tr><td>` tag in the display javascript page.
Now I am able to get the results displayed in proper manner but I am missing the "loadmore" button on the page. I can see that code for the button is displayed in console.log.

Comment: I am not sure but the problem was that I was not able to append any other markup elements besides table. It just would not show up. It may because of the appending done to the table div.
Also, I had to shift the button logic on the javascript side since button was not appending.I ended up using length of the rows to determine the starting point of the next set of database results.